# Can I borrow self immutably for self.callbacks: Vec<Box<FnMut>>?

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Notifier<'a, T> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<'a + FnMut(&T)>>
}

impl<'a, T> Notifier<'a, T>{
    fn add_callback<F: 'a + FnMut(&T)>(&mut self, callback: F) {
        self.callbacks.push(Box::new(callback));
    }

    fn trigger(&mut self, payload: T) {
        for callback in &mut self.callbacks {
            callback(&payload);
        }
    }

}

struct A {
    x: i64
}

impl A {

    fn foo(&mut self, x: &i64) {
        self.x = x + 1;
    }

}


fn test() {
    let mut bar = A {x: 3};
    let mut notifier = Notifier{callbacks: Vec::new()};
    notifier.add_callback(|x| bar.foo(x));

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3610bb1f250c488e09a2e7c505bc26b2&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

This is a simple observer pattern implemented using callbacks. It works.

However, the fact that `trigger(&mut self...` causes much trouble in my later coding ([How to update self based on reference of value from hashmap from self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142080/how-to-update-self-based-on-reference-of-value-from-hashmap-from-self)). Is it possible to make `trigger(&self ...` instead?

I'm using rustc 1.19.0-nightly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the interior of a struct without having the struct mutable, you should use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/):

> Values of the `Cell<T>` and `RefCell<T>` types may be mutated through shared references (i.e. the common `&T` type), whereas most Rust types can only be mutated through unique (`&mut T`) references. We say that `Cell<T>` and `RefCell<T>` provide 'interior mutability', in contrast with typical Rust types that exhibit 'inherited mutability'.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9774ee581e99918859b20248e84223f9&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2ee39c72c43c8cd196b5a65666e1ac89&version=nightly&backtrace=0) where `trigger` uses `&self`