# How to update self based on reference of value from hashmap from self

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::*;

struct A {
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
    i: i32
}
impl A {
    fn test(&mut self) {
        match self.map.get("abc") {
            None => {},
            Some(x) => self.trigger(&x)
        }
    }

    fn trigger(&mut self, x: &str) {
        self.i += 1;
    }
}
```

The code doesn't work because `self.trigger` borrows `self` mutably, while `self.map.get` is keeping an immutable borrow of `self` in scope.

Is there any way to make it work, given that I can make sure in the `trigger` I don't modify `self.map`?

I cannot make `trigger` borrow `self` immutably, as in  [Can I borrow self immutably for self.callbacks: Vec<Box<FnMut>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141829/can-i-borrow-self-immutably-for-self-callbacks-vecboxfnmut)

I'm using rustc 1.19.0-nightly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the borrow checker does not know that `trigger` only changes `self.i`. As far as the borrow checker knows, it might also change `self.map`, which would be unsafe.

The solution is to tell the borrow checker more about what `trigger` changes.

One way to do this is by moving everything that `trigger` needs to borrow mutablely into its own struct, and then implement trigger for that struct:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::*;

struct TriggerThing {
    i: i32
}

impl TriggerThing {
    fn trigger(&mut self, _: &HashMap<String, String>, x: &str) {
        self.i += 1;
    }
}

struct A {
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
    trigger_thing: TriggerThing,
}

impl A {
    fn test(&mut self) {
        // Its fine to have a immutable borrow of self.map
        // and a mutable borrow of self.trigger_thing at the
        // same time, since borrowing self.trigger_thing does not
        // imply a mutable borrow of self.map.
        if let Some(x) = self.map.get("abc") {
            // Notice that we can still give self.trigger_thing
            // access to self.map, as long as we only
            // give it an immutable reference
            self.trigger_thing.trigger(&self.map, &x)
        }
    }
}
```

see [Rust Book: If Let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/if-let.html) if you haven't seen the awesome `if let` syntax it before.